# Blender 4: 4D Noise Texture animate with Sound to Samples?

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

In Blender 4, I have a Noise Texture set to 4D and I am trying to animate the W value to audio but the option 'Sound to Samples' is greyed out.

How is it possible to get this working?

Thank you.